# Struts2 grid json

Tags: json, hibernate, serialization, struts2, lazy-initialization

How can I exclude Hibernate objects that are listed as FetchType.LAZY?  It causes problems because I get a org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException.  I understand that it is trying to serialize the object and it can not because the session is closed.  How can I disable it?  I have many objects that do this and it would not be feasible to make them eager nor to remove them as there are too many of them.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use includeProperties as suggested by nmc, however it would still be nice to not have to define the properties and see if JSONUtil can just ignore lazy loaded objects.

```
<result name="success" type="json">
    <param name="includeProperties"> ^gridModel\[\d+\]\.first, ^gridModel\[\d+\]\.last, rows, page, total, record</param>               
</result>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your struts.xml:

```
<result name="success" type="json">
    <param name="excludeProperties">
        <!-- insert comma separated parameters to be excluded here -->
    </param>
</result>
```

Or you can also do an `includeProperties`.  See http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html for more details.

Comment: Only problem is that it is very deep.  For example:
    Employee {
      String firstname;
      String lastname;
      Address address;
      
      AddressSet <>
    }
    Address {
         String street;
         Country country;
    }

It goes deeper and deeper.  Just listing them out takes too much effort, is it possible to reduce


If I only wanted to include say 3 properties, how would I do that with struts2-jquery: Action class has List<Employee> gridModel

What do I do now to include only first and last name
<param name="includeProperties">first, last, ...</param> - does not work

Comment: @Johnny Ekkkl: Did you try `<param name="includeProperties">employee.firstname, employee.lastname...`?  You may also include `*` as a wildcard.  Examples are in the documentation.